# Updating foreground service everyday at an exact time

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-workmanager

I've written an application with a foreground service.
The service notification must be updated precisely at 6 pm every day.

I've tried to achieve this functionality with `AlarmManager` but most of the time it is not working.
Would `WorkManager` solve this problem (if it is, please explain how I should use it in this case) or is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just FYI: https://dontkillmyapp.com/ as you don't describe how you are testing.

Answer (score 0):

WorkManager is the sure bet for your use case. According to the documentation:

> WorkManager is the recommended solution for persistent work. Work is persistent when it remains scheduled through app restarts and system reboots.

More specifically, you would need to schedule a Deferrable work, which is a task that starts at a later time and can run periodically.